# Multiplicative "Gaussian" Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Forgive my lack of understanding, but I'm looking for a continuous distribution where for some mean $\mu$ and real number $a > 0$, the probability of choosing $\frac{\mu}{a}$ and $a\mu$ is equally likely.

Just as an example, let $\mu = 1$, and $a = 2$. In a regular gaussian graphed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5QN7.png), it's obvious that values chosen will be skewed to be higher than the mean (as there's more area from [1,2] than [0.5,1]). Basically, what I'm looking for is a distribution that fixes this, resulting in the same area from [1,2] as [0.5,1] (for this example, but more generally [$\frac{\mu}{a}$, $\mu$] and [$\mu$, $a\mu$]).

I feel like this has to be a thing, I just haven't worked much with probability, and don't know exactly what to google.

Comment: So you want the logarithm of your random quantity to have a symmetric distribution?

Comment: Use a Gaussian mixture, with $\frac{1}{2}$ as mixture value and means $\mu$ and $\frac{\mu}{a}$. The variance of the two  is an arbitrary parameter but with similar scaling. I mean $\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)+\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\frac{\mu}{a},\frac{\sigma^2}{a^2})$. Does this works? You can also use a multivariate Gaussian.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I went ahead and quickly checked, and I'm not sure if that's working unless I've done something wrong. Here's a quick [check](https://imgur.com/5fmRvlp), where I've chosen $\mu = 1$, $a = 2$, $\sigma ^2 = 1$

Comment: A continuous random variable has each point with probability $0$ so you may intend density rather than probability, but that causes other issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a random variable $X$ such that

$$\int_{\mu/a}^{\mu}f_X(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mu}^{\mu a}f_X(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$$

If we make the change of variable $x=e^u$, (with $\mathrm{d}x=e^u\mathrm{d}u$), we have

$$\int_{\log \mu - \log a}^{\log\mu}f_X(e^u)e^u\;\mathrm{d}u=\int_{\log\mu}^{\log \mu + \log a}f_X(e^u)e^u\;\mathrm{d}u$$

This must hold for all $a$, so $f_U(u)=f_X(e^u)e^u$ must be symmetric about $\log\mu$. Therefore, what you need to do is:

1. Pick any continuous distribution $f_U(u)$ that is symmetric about $\log\mu$.
2. Compute a new distribution $f_X(x)=\frac{f_U(\log x)}{x}$. This is, as kimchi lover's comment says, the probability density function of $X=e^U$.
3. The distribution $f_X(x)$ satisfies your criterion.

For example, if you apply this procedure starting with a Gaussian distribution, you get the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), which satisfies your criterion (note that the Wikipedia article defines $\mu$ differently: you need to use $\log\mu$ here):

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\left(\log x - \log \mu\right)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

**Edit:** this method produces random variables $X$ that satisfy

$$\mathrm{Pr}\left[X\in\left[\frac{\mu}{a}, \mu\right]\right]=\mathrm{Pr}\left[X\in[\mu, \mu a]\right]\qquad\quad(1)$$

for a fixed $\mu$ and any $a$, but it does **not** make the mean $\mathrm{E}[X]$ equal to $\mu$. We have shown that, for (1) to hold, it is required that $U=\log X$ is symmetric about $\log\mu$. As pointed out by [guy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12806/guy) in the comments, this means that $\mathrm{E}[U]=\log\mu$, and Jensen's inequality tells us that

$$\mathrm{E}[X]=\mathrm{E}[e^U]\ge e^{\mathrm{E}[U]}=\mu.\qquad\quad(2)$$

As $e^U$ is a strictly convex function, equality holds only when $U$ is constant. Therefore, the only distribution that satisfies (1) **and** has mean $\mu$ is the constant distribution

$$\textrm{Pr}[X=\mu]=1.$$

Comment: If the distribution is symmetric about $\log\mu$ then $\mu$ cannot be the mean of $X$ by Jensen’s inequality. @Whisper specifies in the OP that $\mu$ is the mean.

Comment: Does your log-normal example work to give equal densities for $\mu=1$ and $a=2$? I am thinking about the effect of the $\frac1x$ at the start

Comment: Might be a different question all together, but (at least for your $f_X(x)$ above), this would put the median at $\mu$ rather than the mean. Is there an alternative approach where the mean stays at $\mu$?

Comment: @Whisper I think guy's comment proves that it is not possible to find a non-constant distribution that satisfies your criterion and has the mean at $\mu$. I have added this to the answer.

Comment: @guy I think your comment already proves that the only distribution that satisfies both OP's constraints is the constant distribution (I added this to the answer). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Henry yes, if you apply the substitution $u=\log x$ in both integrals, you get the integral of the Gaussian distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. In the first case, the integral goes from $-\log 2$ to $0$, and in the second case it goes from $0$ to $\log 2$, so both are the same.

Comment: Yes, unless I am making a blunder, your argument shows that the distribution must be symmetric about $\log \mu$ and Jensen shows that $\mu$ can’t be the mean unless the distribution is a point mass.